# How to make jTable data depended on combobox in Java GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, combobox, jtable

I am trying to change data sets by changing semester selected in which the last character in combobox is its number. Substring method gets it and puts in an SQL query. But when I select "Semester 1", all jTable is full of data, on the other hand data sets cannot be changed when I select other options in combobox. It's like jTable is freezed.

http://www.wklejto.pl/743607 - here You can find my code.

Comment: Do you get any errors? And is this return a string? `selectName.substring(8, 9)`

Comment: No I do not have any errors and selectName.substring(8, 9) returns a string, but I exchange it now on integer value by Integer.parseint(). Still the same, jTable is freeze. :/